# i need assistance : this while updating user information

Tags: mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIkhA.png)
please this error is showing up while i'm trying to update the last_name & first_name of a user
any help please ? (i'm using Linux)

please this error is showing up while i'm trying to update the last_name & first_name of a user
any help please ? (i'm using Linux)
please open the image above to see it clearly

> db.contactList.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("6378c0336c5f81777d8bd4a5")} {$set:{"Last_name":"Kefi"}, {"First_name":"Anis"}}));
> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :
> @(shell):1:70
> db.contactList.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("6378c0336c5f81777d8bd4a5")} {$set:{Last_name:"Kefi"}, {First_name:"Anis"}});
> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :
> @(shell):1:70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
db.contacts.updateOne(
  {
    _id: ObjectId('6377ce54ffd3270e15035da7') // id of document you want to update
  }, 
  {
     $set: {
       "Last_name": "Kefi", 
       "First_name": "Anis"
    }
  }
);
```

Make sure you have exact same properties in you schema.

If you want to use `update` method then try this:

```
db.contacts.update(
  {
    _id: ObjectId('6377ce54ffd3270e15035da7') // id of document you want to update
  }, 
  {
     $set: {
       "Last_name": "Kefi", 
       "First_name": "Anis"
    }
  }
);
```